# How do I use this this egg just called "spawn"

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was randomly doing /give "tab" when suddenly I saw a item called "spawn".

Can you give me backup information about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a blank spawn egg. It does not have any use, and can only be obtained through use of commands.

If you want to give yourself a spawn egg that can actually spawn an entity, you should use:

```
/give @p minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {EntityTag:{id:Pig}}
```

Where "Pig" is the entity ID that you want to spawn (only entities normally spawnable from spawn eggs work, so you can't use this to make an iron golem spawn egg or anything).